# Lodash Not executing the nested method,

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, lodash

given this array `var array = [{a:1, b: 2, c: 3}, {a: 2, b: 4, c: 4}]`.

I want to iterate through each item in the array and omit the key `c` and it's value using lodash.

here is the method I tried

`_.each(array, function (obj) {
 return _.omit(obj, ['a']);
});`

Expected Output should be `// [{b: 2, c: 3}, {b: 4, c: 4} ]`
but lodash returns the original array`// [{a:1, b: 2, c: 3}, {a: 2, b: 4, c: 4}]`

Comment: I'm guessing you mean you want to omit `a`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `forEach()` to return new modified array you should use `map()`, also first parameter is array.

```js
var array = [{a:1, b: 2, c: 3}, {a: 2, b: 4, c: 4}]

var result = _.map(array, function (obj) {
 return _.omit(obj, ['a']);
});

console.log(JSON.stringify(result, 0, 4))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.15.0/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

A probably-not-the-lo-dash-iest way of handling it (assuming you actually want to omit `a`):

```
_.each(lnkn, function (obj) {
    var returnObj = {};
    for (prop in obj) {
        if (obj.hasOwnProperty(prop) {
            if (prop !== 'a') {
                returnObj[prop] = obj[prop];
            }
        }
    }
    return returnObj;
});
```

Comment: @Nenad's answer is definitely better.

Answer (score 0):

[`_.forEach`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.16.4#forEach) is supposed to return the original array. You re looking for [`_.map`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.16.4#map).

```js
const array = [{a:1, b: 2, c: 3}, {a: 2, b: 4, c: 4}];
const result = _.map(array, obj => _.omit(obj, 'a'));
console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.4/lodash.js"></script>
```

Or you can modify the objects in place:

```js
const array = [{a:1, b: 2, c: 3}, {a: 2, b: 4, c: 4}];
_.forEach(array, obj => {
    delete obj.a;
});
console.log(array);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.4/lodash.js"></script>
```

Comment: Yeah! that's what I found out. I used ```_.map(array, (obj) =>  _.omit(obj, 'a'));``` and it worked fine.